# file path for default text, mysql

Tags: mysql, default

I want the following to be the default text in my column

```
  "profile-pictures/default.jpeg"
```

the SQL I am using to set the column up is

```
  PictureFilePath varchar(255) DEFAULT 'profile-pictures/default.jpeg'
```

but when I add a row the column has

```
  "profile-pictures/"
```

why is it missing the file name?

Comment: is your column a `text` column or a `varchar`? is it's `length` long enough to hold the entire string?

Comment: please paste the code where you insert the data into the database

Comment: @mugur PictureFilePath varchar(255) DEFAULT 'profile-pictures/default.jpeg'

Comment: @BrianGlaz it is a varchar(255) so it should be long enough

Comment: i think, there is any other problem, pls debug check the your inserting value is correct

Comment: tryed to make a table with your default value and it works without a problem. give us the insert statement please.